# Wordpress: How to Search within a specific category by slug (category name)

Tags: wordpress

How can I create a code which would search **by slug(category name)** but not by ID. How can I create a customized solution for my client for search within a specific category (without any plugins)?

Explain: I want the code of search to be customized in such a way that the client could search within a specific category without editing any code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is it's still actually, you should to check [this tutorial](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/03/advanced-wordpress-search-with-wp_query/#4-build-the-search-form) where an author gives a very detailed explanation about the Search function customization.

One of the most interesting parts for a necessary your case:

```
// meta_query expects nested arrays even if you only have one query
$sm_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'accommodation', 'posts_per_page' => '-1', 'meta_query' => array( array( 'key' => '_sm_accommodation_city' ) ) ) );

// The Loop
if ( $sm_query->have_posts() ) {
    $cities = array();
    while ( $sm_query->have_posts() ) {
        $sm_query->the_post();
        $city = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_sm_accommodation_city', true );

        // populate an array of all occurrences (non duplicated)
        if( !in_array( $city, $cities ) ){
            $cities[] = $city;    
        }
    }
}
} else{
       echo 'No accommodations yet!';
       return;
}


/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();

if( count($cities) == 0){
    return;
}

asort($cities);

$select_city = '<select name="city" style="width: 100%">';
$select_city .= '<option value="" selected="selected">' . __( 'Select city', 'smashing_plugin' ) . '</option>';
foreach ($cities as $city ) {
    $select_city .= '<option value="' . $city . '">' . $city . '</option>';
}
$select_city .= '</select>' . "\n";

reset($cities);
```